# Accessing AppSettings.json value from a model class

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a calculated field in a class used for photos which prepends a url to the filename, I want to be able to add a base url for the photos (which is to an azure storage account) which will come from the appsettings file.

Initially I created a strongly typed class to access the settings, and I can inject it just fine to say a service class, but how can I access this in a model class?  Am I completely going in the wrong direction with this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When instantiating the model, you could inject your strongly typed settings class, as long as the model already has a dependency on that.  Alternatively, you'd need to move the calculation of that field out of the model, or simply provide the base URL to the model from your service classes.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply.  Just tried to simply retrieve the value from the service and then use that in the controller and it works.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating the model, you could inject your strongly typed settings class, as long as the model already has a dependency on that. Alternatively, you'd need to move the calculation of that field out of the model, or simply provide the base URL to the model from your service classes.